# formatting email body using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, string-formatting, outlook-2010

I have the following section of code, which is part of an automatic reply system im developing. As i understand it, it *should* format the body of the email with line breaks, but, as the attached screenshot shows, it doesnt. Can somebody point oput where im going wrong?

```
With NewForward
            .Subject = "'TEST' Hazard report reciept number: HAZ" & IDnumber
            .To = strSender
            .BCC = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            .HTMLBody = "Please accept this email as confirmation that xxxx has received your road defect notification. xxxxx will investigate and action your notification according to priority and to ensure public safety. For further information, please phone xxxxx on 4221 6111 and quote reference number " & vbCrLf & IDnumber & vbCrLf & "Your original report can be seen below:" & vbCrLf & report_body
            .Send
        End With
```

Image:
[image: Email Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `.HTMLBody` then you should write it using `HTML Tags`.
Try this:

```
Dim EBody as String

EBody = "Please accept this email as confirmation that xxxx has received your road defect notification." & "<br>" _
    & "xxxxx will investigate and action your notification according to priority and to ensure public safety." & "<br>" _
    & "For further information, please phone xxxxx on 4221 6111 and quote reference number:" & "<br>" _
    & IDnumber & "Your original report can be seen below:" & "<br>" _
    & reportbody

With NewForward
    .Subject = "'TEST' Hazard report reciept number: HAZ" & IDnumber
    .To = strSender
    .BCC = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    .HTMLBody = Ebody
    .Send
End With
```

Hope this works for you.
Also your `reportbody` should be in the same format using `HTML Tags`.

Comment: glad it did :D you can also change font type, font color, font size using `HTML Tags`. If you like to learn more, you can start [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/). It also allows you to see the result of the code you generated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the value you are setting the HTMLBody property to does not include any HTML formatting...

Your constants like `vbCrLf` do not format the HTML. Use HTML tags instead, e.g. `<br>` for a line break.