# Add Excel data to mail

Tags: excel, vba

The following code generates mail to send an Excel sheet as a .pdf document.

I would like to customize the body of the e-mail with a range of cells from the actual Excel sheet on a different tab. So basically I have pre-written text pulling figures from the Excel sheet that I want to use as my automated body.

```
Sub Email_ActiveSheet_As_PDF()

'Do not forget to change the email ID
'before running this code

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileFullPath As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Temporary file path where pdf
' file will be saved before
' sending it in email by attaching it.

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

' Now append a date and time stamp
' in your pdf file name. Naming convention
' can be changed based on your requirement.

TempFileName = ActiveSheet.Name & "-" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".pdf"

'Complete path of the file where it is saved
FileFullPath = TempFilePath & TempFileName

'Now Export the Activesshet as PDF with the given File Name and path

On Error GoTo err
With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=FileFullPath, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

'Now open a new mail

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "michaelbrentklein@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "2014 Pickup Report Now Available"
    .Body = **NEED HELP HERE**
    .Attachments.Add FileFullPath '--- full path of the pdf where it is saved
    .Send   'or use .Display to show you the email before sending it.
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

'Since mail has been sent with the attachment
'Now delete the pdf file from the temp folder

Kill FileFullPath

'set nothing to the objects created
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'Now set the application properties back to true
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
MsgBox ("Email has been Sent Successfully")
Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: If it is ok that the email body is not formatted, you can assign it directly to `.Body`. Something like `.Body = Range("A1").Value`. However if you like it to be formatted using `.HtmlBody`, then you have to create/make the range value in Html tagged format and then assign it directly to `.HtmlBody` or manipulate it inside the code. [Here's how you format email body using Html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248365/formatting-email-body-using-vba/21248730#21248730).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VBA from my beloved lazy-man daily dashboard that I think does what your trying to accomplish...  I wrote this for a similar situation awhile ago and I've been using it daily for 3+ years now.  I don't know if you are updating links on your file before you send the PDF, but I included it just in case...

You can set a scheduler task in windows to auto open this file every day at XX:XX time The only requirement is the computer is on and the user logged in or at the locked screen.

**Here is the features it can offer you.**

1. Update all the workbook links
2. Include specific cell data into your email body or subject/to/cc/bcc
           (I used it to include all my email styling and html markup )
3. Save the File to PDF format
4. Email the File to a specified email address or distribution group
5. Save the Excel File with the new values
6. Close the Excel File after X amount of time

   ```
       (for the instances where you're not at the computer when this runs)
   ```

**You can put each code block in a separate module.**

**Make sure your Workbook_Open code goes in the standard This.Workbook module.. **

**The Workbook_Open includes the calls to the rest of the standalone module's functions**

## VBA CODE

Look for inline comments and update values to get it to fit your needs

---

**Put this code within the This.Workbook Module**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
    .UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksAlways
End With
Run ("UpdateLinks")
Run ("SavePDF")
Run ("SendEmail")
Run ("SaveIt")
Run ("MsgBoxDelay")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

**Update All Cell Links**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Links As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
'   Change sheet YourSheetName to suit
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")
    Links = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
    If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
                                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Workbooks.Open Links(i)
            Sh.Calculate
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
                                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Save the Excel =to> PDF**

```
Sub SavePDF()
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Update this path to match where you would like the PDF to be saved from.
  'NOTE THIS LOCATION AS IT WILL BE USED FOR ATTACHING THE FILE TO SEND VIA EMAIL

    ChDir "\\NameofDrive\NameofDirectory\FolderName\FileName"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="\\NameofDrive\NameofDirectory\FolderName\FileName.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False  ' Optional open PDF once finished..

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

**Email Module**

```
Sub SendEmail()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailMarkup As String
Dim Send As Boolean
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim headerTxt As String
    headerTxt = Range("n1").Text 'change o1 to the cell you want to reference
Dim bodyTxt As String
    bodyTxt = Range("o1").Text 'change o1 to the cell you want to reference
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = "" 'put email or distribution group name.
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""

.Subject = "Email Subject"
.EmailMarkup = "<html><header>" & " " & headerTxt & "<header>" & bodyTxt & "</body></html>"
.attachments.Add ("\\NameofDrive\NameofDirectory\FolderName\FileName.pdf")  'add the full file path to your attachment if you want to use this function..

.Send 'or use .Display

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

---

**Save the Excel file new values**

```
    Sub SaveIt()
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ChDir "\\NameofDrive\NameofDirectory\FolderName\" 'update to the correct folder
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

---

**Popup to prevent the file from closing once the timer has ran out. Plus the function to**
**Save/Close Excel after specified amount of time without intervention by user.**

```
 Declare Function MessageBoxTimeout Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpText As String, _
    ByVal lpCaption As String, _
    ByVal uType As Long, _
    ByVal wLanguageID As Long, _
    ByVal lngMilliseconds As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long


Public Sub MsgBoxDelay()
        Const cmsg As String = "This work book will auto-close in 30 seconds.  Click YES to CLOSE FILE, Click NO to KEEP OPEN"
        Const cTitle As String = "This work book will auto-close in 30 seconds.Close the Excel File?"
        Dim retval As Long
        retval = MessageBoxTimeout((FindWindow(vbNullString, Title)), cmsg, cTitle, 4, 0, 60000)

        If retval <> 7 Then
            Call SaveIt
            ThisWorkbook.Close
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the quick answer to your question as well.. Just grab the text from the fields using Range() and then wrap the text into the html markup as shown in .EmailMarkup..                                               `Dim headerTxt As String
     headerTxt = Range("n1").Text 'change 
     Dim bodyTxt As String
     bodyTxt = Range("o1").Text 'change 
     EmailMarkup As String 
     With OutMail
     .EmailMarkup = "<html><header>" & " " & headerTxt & "<header>" & bodyTxt & "</body></html>"`