# Reformat an Outlook email so each word has randomized font, size, color, and highlight

Tags: css, vba, fonts, outlook

I want to create a macro, so that after I draft an email in Outlook it will be reformatted so that each word is a different font, size, color, and highlight.

Ideally, I would be able to constrain fonts, font sizes, and highlight frequency to maintain readability.

[The goal is to achieve this kind of transformation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31GB2.png)

I've never even attempted a project like this. What tool would most effectively implement this? Would I be able to package it and share it with others?

I want to use this as a learning opportunity, but need a kick in the right direction for what I need to understand to start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I hope you never intend to actually *send* a message like that to anyone. If you do, the gods of Email will come down and squash you.

Now: you can use Outlook VBA and the [`MailItem.HTMLBody` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941.aspx) to set or modify the HTML text that is the body of the email. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248365/formatting-email-body-using-vba).

But be aware that the CSS support of Outlook is extremely limited, so you'd better use HTML tags to format the text, not CSS.